# validation error mongodb even after passing the json in right format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the problem with the code guyz . whenever i pass the post request with json , validation error - "path confirmPassword is required " logged  in the console . i had used body-parser and express.json() too but it didn't work for me .

```
const Loginschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : [true , 'please enter your name'],
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : [true ,' please enter your email'],
        unique : true,
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    confirmPassword : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        validate : {
            validator(value){
                return value === this.password;
            }
        }
    }
})


// -----------------------> HASHING PASSWORD <--------------------

Loginschema.pre('save' , async function (request , response , next) {
    if(!this.isModified('password')) return next();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password , 10);
    this.confirmPassword = undefined;
    next();
})
```

Here are the middleware i used

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

this is the error i got on console

```
    properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Path `confirmPassword` is required.',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'confirmPassword',
        value: undefined
      },
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'confirmPassword',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'loginData validation failed'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Loginschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : [true , 'please enter your name'],
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : [true ,' please enter your email'],
        unique : true,
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    confirmPassword : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        validate : {
            validator: function (value) {
                return value === this.password;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**validator** is an attribute. [Official Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators)